# How to pass Sp entityId from Idp to Shibboleth Sp?

Tags: shibboleth

I am not sure but is it possible to pass entityId in AuthnStatement to Shibboleth SP? I am already sending uid in response AuthnStatement.

Suppose a request is coming to Idp from SP having entityId as **https://sp.example.com/Shibboleth**. After authentication, Idp should post uid as well as entityId to SP.

Let me know if this is possible or is there any way to get entityId attribute in IdP attribute-resolver.xml file.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why do you need that? Don't your SP know its own entityId?

Comment: I am looking for few things:
1.Based on Sp entityId, I need to hit DB to fetch some value at IdP side using RDBMS DataConnector. So, I am not sure how to fetch this value in attribute_resolver.xml file. I believe this must be already present in some variable just i don't know how to fetch it,
2.I want to pass SP as well as Idp entityId as CustomAttribute.

Comment: why don't you get these things using your host/domain. You are anyways mapping your host with some idp. You can always make a map with key as host and value as your desired entity id in your server side code. and checking for host is very easy. i.e. `request.getHeader("host")` - symbolik

Answer (score 1):

Now, I know the answer and updating it so that It can help other as well.

We don't have to worry about Idp URL at SP Side as once the Shibboleth session gets established, It stores all the information like Shibboleth Idp, Authnmethod, and other released parameters into the session.

Once you hit your protected resources, it set all those attributes into headers and can be easily fetched in your application.

Eg: get Idp URL

```
request.getHeader("Shib-Identity-Provider")
```

Check [here](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPAttributeAccess) for the list of headers.